# Simple way to get data from IoT Hub in C#

Tags: c#, azure, iot, azure-iot-hub

I try use code from MS tutorial https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-csharp-csharp-getstarted and this

```
internal class Program
{
private static string connectionString = "HostName=...=";
private static string d2cEndpoint = "messages/events";
private static EventHubClient eventHubClient;

private static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Receive messages\n");
    eventHubClient = EventHubClient.
       CreateFromConnectionString(
          connectionString, d2cEndpoint);

    var d2cPartitions = eventHubClient.
            GetRuntimeInformation().PartitionIds;

    foreach (string partition in d2cPartitions)
    {
        ReceiveMessagesFromDeviceAsync(partition);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}

private async static Task ReceiveMessagesFromDeviceAsync(
                                      string partition)
{
    var eventHubReceiver = eventHubClient.
          GetDefaultConsumerGroup().
            CreateReceiver(partition, DateTime.UtcNow);
    while (true)
    {
        EventData eventData = await eventHubReceiver.
                                            ReceiveAsync();
        if (eventData == null) continue;

        string data = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(
                                  eventData.GetBytes());
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format(
          "Message received. Partition: {0} Data: '{1}'",
          partition, data));
    }
}
}
```

to get data from IoT Hub, but still something was wrong. 
It is possible to get this data in easy way?

Comment: "still something was wrong" -> what, exactly. Are you getting exceptions? define "something"

Comment: we really need some error codes, output stuff to help us help you.

Comment: @PeterBons program after start return error "Unhandled Exception: System.IO.FileNotFoundExpection: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Service.Bus, Version 3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=XXX' or one of its dependencies." dll is in the directory with exe. What is wrong?

Comment: Are you using .net Core?  The WindowsAzure.ServiceBus package is not supported on .net Core.

Answer (score 1):

Using the VS2017 version >=15.3.1 you can create an Azure Functions project for *EventHubTrigger* function without any single line code. The following template code snippet shows this function:

```
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.ServiceBus;

namespace FunctionApp4
{
public static class Function1
{
    [FunctionName("Function1")]
    public static void Run([EventHubTrigger("myEventHubName", Connection = "myIoTHub")]string myEventHubMessage, TraceWriter log)
    {
        log.Info($"C# Event Hub trigger function processed a message: {myEventHubMessage}");
    }
}
```

}

and the local.settings.json file:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=...;AccountKey=...",
    "AzureWebJobsDashboard": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=...;AccountKey=...",
    "myIoTHub": "Endpoint=sb://....servicebus.windows.net/;SharedAccessKeyName=iothubowner;SharedAccessKey=..."
  }
}
```

The following screen snippet shows a console output of the local azure function:
[image: Function1]